# switch from svn to tfs visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, version-control, tfs

We are in the process of migrating from SVN to TFS. I got latest code from SVN to local folder and checked in the soultion to TFS. Now I want to go back to SVN to get the latest updated files from SVN. I did unbind the solution from TFS in Visual Studion 2010. I also changed Tools --> Options -->Source Control plugin to SVN from Visual Studio 2010. But I couldn't see "SVN Update" to get the latest files from SVN. How can I switch between the source controls? I would like to get latest files from SVN and check in the changes to TFS. Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices, either:

a) "Checkout for Edit" all the files in the TFS Folder. Then do an SVN Export of the latest code into that folder. Then do a "[TFPT /uu](http://aka.ms/tfpt)" to undo all unchanged edits. Perform a review of the pending changes and check those into TFS.

b) Delete everything from TFS and SVN Export your repo and re-add it all to TFS.